# Don't know if this is a Complete Binary Tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Okay I know what a complete binary tree means. It means, "All levels are completely filled except possibly the last level and the last level has all nodes as left as possible."

In an exam paper answers, it is saying this tree below isn't a complete binary tree.

```
   5
 /    \
3      6
     /
     5
```

Why isn't this a complete binary tree? The last level has a node that's on the far left as possible.

Comment: The last level has only a 5 in it (which is OK), but that 5 is not as far left as possible.  It should be the left child of 3

Comment: Ahhhh. If that's the case, then thank you. :) I've been pulling my hair out and Stack Overflow was my last hope!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it rose from a simple misunderstanding of some written text.